# Pinch interface that connects the displays of multiple devices simultaneously

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oop

I want to implement Pinch interface that connects the displays of multiple devices simultaneously
here is the concept video.

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRGLkj-PsCc

I am unable to get any clue to start. Is there any one that can help me to implement for Android Devices.